# Pushing Jar to github when a Jenkins build succeeds

Tags: jar, github, hudson, jenkins, publish

I have a simple Jenkins build that pulls down my project from github, builds it and reports the status of the build.

I want to have configure Jenkins to publish the resulting JAR file to a TARGET-SNAPSHOTS branch in my project.

Currently my project .gitignore's /target/*

I was looking at GitPublisher but this appears to push the entire build out, rather than just the jar file.

Thoughts on the best way to do this/if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using maven to build your project?

Comment: Are you trying to add a file to an existing repo and push the changes OR add a file to GitHub's download section?

Comment: @brian -- Yes - I am using maven to build my project.

Comment: @ŁukaszRżanek -- I was thinking a branch, but Downloads should work as well. I just want to make the built OSGI Bundle (Jar file) easily available for download for other to install (instead of having them download the source and package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using maven and you said the github downloads section is acceptable, you can use the github downloads plugin - https://github.com/github/maven-plugins. I use this for deploying the Riak java client to our downloads section as part of the build.

In your ~/.m2/settings.xml you need:

```
<settings>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>github</id>
      <properties>
        <github.global.userName>YourGithubUser</github.global.userName>
        <github.global.password>YourGithubPass</github.global.password>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>github</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Then in your project's `.pom` something like:

```
<profile>
  <id>githubUpload</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>github.downloads</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.github</groupId>
        <artifactId>downloads-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <description>${project.version} release of ${project.name}</description>
          <override>false</override>               
          <includeAttached>true</includeAttached>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>upload</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>install</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

(I'm doing it as part of the install phase - you can do however you'd like)

Then simply add `-Dgithub.downloads=true` to your maven build -

`mvn install -Dgithub.downloads=true`

The web page for the plugin lists all the options for including/excluding files, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have many possibility. One of them is to run post-build script. It can be written is shell.

See [Post build task](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task)

Simple script:

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec scp {} user@myhost.com:/path/for/build/${BUILD_TAG} \;
```

Other:

[Publish Over ... (ssh, ftp, cifs)](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+...)

Comment: I will try it out - i didnt realize you could SCP to github. Thanks